# Как в Bootstrap 4 изменить ширину блоков col-*?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, sass

Как в Bootstrap 4 изменить ширину блоков `col-*`?

Answer (score 3):

Есть несколько возможных вариантов, зависит от конкретной задачи:

1. Можно менять ширину колонок в стандартной сборке бустрапа меняя постфиксы в классах колонок от 1 до 12, в зависимости от выбранной ширины экрана.

```css
.foo {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-3 col-sm-5 col-md-12 col-lg-4'>
      <div class='foo'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-3 col-xl-5 col-md-12 col-lg-4'>
      <div class='foo'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-3 col-sm-5 col-md-12 col-lg-4'>
      <div class='foo'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

2. Вы можете сами создать свою колонку, нужной вам ширины, например ширина 25%, которой нет в бутстрапе. Добавьте класс `.col` и для нужного класса пропишите свой процент на все ширины:

```css
.foo {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  background: purple;
}

.col-25 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .col-sm-25 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-md-25 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-25 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-xl-25 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col col-25 col-sm-25 col-md-25 col-lg-25 col-xl-25'>
      <div class='foo'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='col col-25 col-sm-25 col-md-25 col-lg-25 col-xl-25'>
      <div class='foo'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='col col-25 col-sm-25 col-md-25 col-lg-25 col-xl-25'>
      <div class='foo'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='col col-25 col-sm-25 col-md-25 col-lg-25 col-xl-25'>
      <div class='foo'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

3. Вы можете [кастомизировать](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#sass-options) свою сборку под собственные нужды используя переменные `sass`. В файле `_variables.scss` переменные, изменив которые собрать свою тему со своей сеткой.

> $grid-columns: 12 !default;

Например заменить на любое требуемое вам количество, допустим 100:

> $grid-columns: 100;

И тогда у вас появятся колонки с ширинами на все размеры брейкпоинтов от 0 до 100. Вы сможете например создать колонку шириной 95%, или 13%, любое целое число от 0 до 100, можно попасть почти в любой макет!

4. В [третьем бутстрапе есть собственный кастомизатор прямо на сайте](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/), можно ввести аргументы и скачать свою версию. В 4 вы это можете сделать сами вручную, как в примере выше.